# displaying data in table format without using DataGrid/ListView/Table in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I need to display data in the UI in a table format. I am using wpf (MVVM), VS 2010 and windows XP. I do not want to use the DataGrid or ListView. How can I achieve this?

*What I have tried*

- **Method 1:**

  I tried to use SharedSizeGroup but that didn't work. The main problem with using SharedSizeGroup is that even the row height is shared among all rows.
- **Method 2:**

  I tried to use UniformGrid but I was not completely successful. Using UniformGrid will not suite my application because each column data is of different width and I do not want each column to take the same width as the Max of all!

  Can anyone please tell me how to use the normal grid to get the desired result? Is there any way to use SharedSizeGroup so that only the column width is shared but not the row height and each row occupies only desired space (i.e. same behavior as setting the height to auto) but not more than that?

*Additional information*: This grid has to be read-only and no row should be selectable in the UI.

Comment: GridView  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx

Comment: why dont you wanna use some kind of itemscontrol? thats what they for

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use a regular `DataGrid` or `ListView` for this.